# Shape key deforms face automatically

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms

So I've made 2 shape keys so far, but when I tried to do my 3rd and set the value to 1 it automatically deformed for no reason, any suggestions?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hello, do you mean that the deformation is not the one you've created in Edit mode for this shapekey?

Comment: No, right after i create the shapekey, and set it to 1, it deforms, I haven't done any changes to it yet

Comment: could you please share the part with the problem? (upload, it will generate a URL, copy it and paste it here) https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: the file is 31Mb even if I send only the face, it's to large :/

Comment: so use another platform   ;)

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LrO5c5uwdTbWtiBXlTGrpjGeddt7yxVO/view?usp=sharing here

Comment: your link asks for an authorization   ;)

Comment: Sorry >< It's open now to public

Comment: it works as it is supposed to, if I switch to Edit mode and push the Value up to 1 it will also deform the mesh as I see it in Object mode. If you directly want to see the deformed version in Edit mode without having to push the Value, disable the Shape Key Edit Mode option (button above right of the Value bar)

Answer (score 0):

While i have no idea why that happened, i think i've found a solution.

- First, duplicate your mesh with the shape keys and leave it anywere. (this is to save your current shape keys which will stop working on the main mesh, but don't worry we'll bring them back).
- Then, on your main mesh and with the *basis* shape key selected, go to edit mode with all shape keys values on zero.
- Now select all vertices.
- In the vertex tab, click on *Propagate to Shapes*.

Now exiting edit mode and trying to use your shape keys they should do nothing, but new shape keys will also have no deformation coming with them. Now lets bring old shape keys back:

- First, still in your main mesh, delete every shape key, **exept** *basis*, from your main mesh.

Now for every shape key, **except** *basis*:

- Select a shape key on the duplicated mesh (unaltered during the
  procedures above).
- Now select your main mesh while maintaining the duplicate selected.
- On the menu at the side of the shape keys, click in *Transfer Shape Key*

Done, now new shape keys don't deform and you also have your old ones. You can delete the duplicate now. I would save this scene on a new file, just in case this brings new problems.

Remember to unlock the shape keys with the pin button if they are locked and you cant use them (I didn't remember when I was trying to solve this).
You also had a driver in a shape key, just put it again.